# Connecting to RDS with JDBC not working (timeout?)

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a database in amazon rds (free tier) and while I can use mysql in the command line to connect to it, when I try to connect to it with Java using JDBC it never connects. Code is below followed by description:

```
try{
out.print("start") //Debugging of sorts
String url = "jdbc:mysql:cs336dbinstance.clsllw6nuy8q.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/coaches";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
out.print("Connection Prepped");

Connection con = Drivermanager.getConnection(url, "realusernameInCode","realPasswordInCode");

out.print("connected?");
```

This is followed by the commands I actually want to do like make an sql statement and execute the query, get a resultSet...etc

When I run the code (Eclipse for Java EE, set to open in default browser, chrome) the page just keeps loading and loading until it stops after a couple mins and ONLY displays:
startconnection prepped

I used the debugger to go line by line and when I get to the DriverManager.getConnection line it never gets past it

There is nothing strictly saying it times out but that's what appears to be happening...I'm totally new to aws and server-side anything so any help is appreciated. A lot of help will probably tell me about security groups, VPCs, and stuff but write now I have all traffic on all ports allowed on inbound traffic and have checked my security group and VPCs to the other SO posts that had similiar problems but the solutions are not working for me. Maybe there's something else I don't know...please help

Update:
mysql line used to connect:

```
mysql -h cs336dbinstance.clsllw6nuy8q.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u cherrera -p
```

Comment: Can you share mysql command line you used for connect? Have you run netstat while java program was hanging? (Do that and show output for :3306)

Comment: Anything I should look for or grep for when using netstat during the jdbc hanging? I put the output in a file but it's 746 lines so no use in putting it in question...missed your comment about output for 3306, my mistake

Comment: check for port 3306 on other side - the connection to Mysql that should be there. What status does that socket show?

Comment: I'd run a `netstat -na | grep 3306` in that case and see what that shows.

Comment: Telnet to that host on port 3306. If that fails it's simply an access issue not a client issue